# How to add constraints to growing dynamic views programmatically?

Tags: ios

I have array based on its count i want to have multiple uiviews displayed next to each other on a scrollview which i should be able to scroll horizontally till the last view  .How can i add constraints those views programmatically?

how can i add constraints to those Views so that each view will have its edges fixed to the corner of xib for device orientations?

Comment: Have you tried "UIView" "addConstraint:" and "addConstraints:" APIs?

Comment: You can't fix anything to the corner of a xib -- a xib is a file.

Comment: Better you can go with collection view.

Answer (score 0):

It consists of:

1. Defining the height constraints for each subview like so:

   ```
   V:|[subview(==scrollView)]|
   ```

   The `|[subview]|` tells it to adjust the `contentSize` to the height of the subview. The `(==scrollView)` says that the height of the subview should be the same as the `bounds` of the scroll view. (Those two things sounds similar, but they're completely different things.)
2. You want set of horizontal constraints that translate to something like:

   ```
   H:|[subview1(==scrollView)][subview2(==scrollView)][subview3(==scrollView)]|
   ```

So, programmatically, that looks something like:

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled = true

var previousSubview: UIView!
var views: [String: UIView]!

for object in objects {
    let subview = UIView()
    subview.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    scrollView.addSubview(subview)

    views = ["subview" : subview, "scrollView" : scrollView]
    if previousSubview == nil {
        // it's first subview, so leading constraint is to the scroll view

        scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[subview(==scrollView)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
    } else {
        // it's not first subview, so leading constraint is to the previous subview

        views["previousSubview"] = previousSubview
        scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[previousSubview][subview(==scrollView)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
    }

    scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[subview(==scrollView)]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))

    previousSubview = subview
}
scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[previousSubview]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
```

Clearly that's a Swift implementation, but the Objective-C implementation is functionally identical (same API calls, same sets of constraints). But hopefully this illustrates the idea.

---

Having said that, I agree with PraveenM, that a collection view is often a more prudent way to handle this sort of UI. Or, if these subviews are very complicated and would benefit from having their own view controllers associated with them, a page view controller is another alternative. Adding all of these views to the scroll view up front is more complicated and is an extravagant use of memory.